# calling jquery function with dynamic elements

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on a chatting application and I am unable to call a jquery function that updates the information about the likes. The code works when the elements to which the call to the function is attached are initially part of the php page that contains the jquery code. When the elements are added dynamicaly the function call doesn't work. Below is the script and the php line from which the function is called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addLikes(ID,action) {
      $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+ID+' li').each(function(index) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('#tutorial-'+ID+' #rating').val((index+1));
      if(index == $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+ID+' li').index(obj)) {
        return false;   
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: "add_likes.php",
      data:'ID='+ID+'&action='+action,
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='LoaderIcon.gif' />");
    },
    success: function(data){
      var likes = parseInt($('#likes-'+ID).val());
      switch(action) {
        case "like":
          $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Unlike" class="unlike" onClick="addLikes('+ID+',\'unlike\')" />');
          likes = likes+1;
        break;
        case "unlike":
          $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Like" class="like"  onClick="addLikes('+ID+',\'like\')" />')
          likes = likes-1;
        break;
      }
      $('#likes-'+ID).val(likes);
      if(likes>0) {
        $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .label-likes').html(likes+" Like(s)");
      } else {
        $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .label-likes').html('');
      }
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

The element that calls the addLikes function:

```
echo "<input" ." type='" ."button'" ." title='" .ucwords($str_like) ."'" ." class='" .$str_like ."'" ." onClick='" ."addLikes" ."(" .$uploadedpics['ID'] ."," .$str_like .")'" ."/>" ;
```

Where `$str_like` can either be like or unlike(the action).

What could be wrong with calling the function as it is called above?
Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: Please, format, question.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick function is not the good way for make that. You can add your data to a data tag.

> IE : data-pics = $uploadedpics['ID'] and data-like = $str_like

**PHP**

```
echo "<input type='button' title='" .ucwords($str_like) ."'" ." class='yourUniqueClass'" ." data-pics='" .$uploadedpics['ID'] ."' data-like='" .$str_like ."' />" ;
```

Now you can access on this directly by Jquery. Add a unique (`"yourUniqueClass"`) class name and access on data with jquery click function.

```
$(document).on("click","yourUniqueClass", function(){
    addLikes( $(this).attr("data-pics"), $(this).attr("data-like") )
})
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function addLikes(ID,action) {
            $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+ID+' li').each(function(index) {
              $(this).addClass('selected');
              $('#tutorial-'+ID+' #rating').val((index+1));
              if(index == $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+ID+' li').index(obj)) {
                return false;   
              }
            });
            $.ajax({
              url: "add_likes.php",
              data:'ID='+ID+'&action='+action,
              type: "POST",
              beforeSend: function(){
                $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='LoaderIcon.gif' />");
            },
            success: function(data){
              var likes = parseInt($('#likes-'+ID).val());
              switch(action) {
                case "like":
                  $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Unlike" class="unlike" onClick="addLikes('+ID+',\'unlike\')" />');
                  likes = likes+1;
                break;
                case "unlike":
                  $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Like" class="like"  onClick="addLikes('+ID+',\'like\')" />')
                  likes = likes-1;
                break;
              }
              $('#likes-'+ID).val(likes);
              if(likes>0) {
                $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .label-likes').html(likes+" Like(s)");
              } else {
                $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .label-likes').html('');
              }
            }
            });
        }
        $(document).on("click",".yourUniqueClass", function(){
            addLikes( $(this).attr("data-pics"), $(this).attr("data-like") )
        })
    })
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Add you click function into document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(document).on("click","#buttlike", function(){ 
        addLikes( $(this).attr("data-pic"), $(this).attr("data-action") )
    })
     function addLikes(ID,action) {
          $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+ID+' li').each(function(index) {
          $(this).addClass('selected');
          $('#tutorial-'+ID+' #rating').val((index+1));
          if(index == $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+ID+' li').index(obj)) {
            return false;   
          }
        });
        $.ajax({
          url: "add_likes.php",
          data:'ID='+ID+'&action='+action,
          type: "POST",
          beforeSend: function(){
            $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='LoaderIcon.gif' />");
        },
        success: function(data){
          var likes = parseInt($('#likes-'+ID).val());
          switch(action) {
            case "like":
              $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Unlike" class="unlike" onClick="addLikes('+ID+',\'unlike\')" />');
              likes = likes+1;
            break;
            case "unlike":
              $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Like" class="like"  onClick="addLikes('+ID+',\'like\')" />')
              likes = likes-1;
            break;
          }
          $('#likes-'+ID).val(likes);
          if(likes>0) {
            $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .label-likes').html(likes+" Like(s)");
          } else {
            $('#tutorial-'+ID+' .label-likes').html('');
          }
        }
      });
    }
})
```

Comment: Instead of unique class I used unique id. What could be wrong?       
        $(document).on("click","#buttlike", function(){
            addLikes( $(this).attr("data-pic"), $(this).attr("data-action") )
        });
    });
</script>                                                                                                                         
 
 echo "<input" ." class='" .$str_like ."'" ." type='" ."button" ."'"  ." data-pic='" .$uploadedpics['ID'] ."'" ." data-action='" .$str_like ."'"  ." title='" .ucwords($str_like) ."'" ." id='" ."buttlike" ."'"  ."/>" ;

Comment: It is still not working even after modifying it as you instructed.

Comment: Thank you Frank. It is working. It turns out that it was several factors contributing to it not working, after I have done as you instructed and capitalized my main html elements, <BODY> instead of <body> for example, it worked perfectly. Thank you once more.

Comment: I have done an investigation that rules out the capitalization observation. The capitalization of the elements has no effect. I must have spelled one of the elements wrong before. Anyway what stands is that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the object as argument. Like:

In PHP :

```
 $arr = array('id'=>$uploadedpics['ID'], 'str'=>$str_like);
 echo "<input" ." type='" ."button'" ." title='" .ucwords($str_like) ."'" ." class='" .$str_like ."'" ." onClick='addLikes(".json_encode($arr).")'/>" ;
```

Then in javascript:

```
 function addLikes(obj) {
    var id = obj.id;
    var str = obj.str;
     //rest of your code.
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution user254153. I will try your solution as well although the solution given by Frank solved the problem already.

Comment: with this solution you can pass as many parameter as you like and it will be easy to handle.